# Formatting and displaying locals in Stata

Tags: stata

I came across a little puzzle with Stata's locals, display, and quotes..
Consider this example:

```
generate var1 = 54321 in 1

local test: di %10.0gc var1[1]
```

Why is the call:

```
di "`test'"
```

returning

```
54,321
```

Whereas the call:

```
di `test'
```

shows

```
54 321
```

What is causing such behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete the sequence with

(1)

```
. di 54,321
54 321
```

(2)

```
. di "54,231" 
54,321
```

`display` interprets (1) as an instruction to display two arguments, one by one. You get the same result with your last line as (first) the local macro `test` was evaluated and (second) `display` saw the result of the evaluation.

The difference when quotation marks are supplied is that thereby you insist that the argument is a literal string. You get the same result with your first `display` command for the same reasons as just given.

In short, the use of local macros here is quite incidental to the differences in results. `display` never sees the local macro as such; it just sees its contents after evaluation. So, what you are seeing pivots entirely on nuances in what is presented to `display`.

Note further that while you can use a display format in defining the contents of a local macro, that ends that story. A local does not have an attached format that sticks with it. It's just a string (which naturally may mean a string with numeric characters).